# Error recovering emails in Delphi (POP3)

Tags: email, delphi, errors

I'm new to programming with Delphi.

I have the latest version. I'm trying to display my emails using POP3 but I have a problem.

At one point I was wrong and did a loop with POP3.Retrieve() method instead of using POP3.RetrieveHeaders().

Delphi surely have downloaded all emails but when I try to start again, the CheckMessages() method is 0.

I tried using something like POP3.Free() or FreeAndNil(POP3) but nothing works for me, I can not check my mail.

What should I do now? When mail is downloaded to the POP3.Retrieve() method is no longer possible to see him again later?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: this is an outright off-topic, totally ignoring what Programmers is **[about](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour)**: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: You should ask at http://stackoverflow.com/ but be sure to post your code and explain what it is expected to do and goes wrong. @Bart's answer below tells you what went went wrong, but please learn which site to use for which questions.  [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A POP3 server only stores the new emails. Once an email has been retrieved, it is deleted from the server.

So, yes. Those emails that you downloaded accidentally are now completely gone and can't be retrieved again.

Comment: Thank you Bart and sorry i'm new, i was wrong section, excuse me.
It will not happen again :(

Comment: @LucasAmalfitani: Don't worry. I considered your question to be on-topic here or I would not have posted an answer.